# electron leaflet map downloads only after windows resize

Tags: javascript, leaflet, electron

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIKzs.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzC9b.png)

leaflet.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/leaflet/my_leaflet.css">

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    // Initialize leaflet.js
    var L = require('leaflet');

    // Initialize the map
    var map = L.map('map', {
        scrollWheelZoom: false
    });

    // Set the position and zoom level of the map
    map.setView([49.42854, 32.06207], 6);

    // Initialize the base layer
    var osm_mapnik = L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; OSM Mapnik <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(map);

    $.getJSON("templates/leaflet/Ukraine.json", function (data) {
        L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
    });
</script>
```

my_leaflet.css

```
#map
{
    width: auto;
    height: 700px;
    position: absolute; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    right:0; 
    left:0;
}

body { margin:0; padding:0;  }
```

When I start my Electron.js application and click the link to page 'leaflet.html', I see the map as at the first image.

But if resize application window to any size the map downloads good as at the second image.

I tried https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3002 and [Leaflet flipping tiles in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586793/leaflet-flipping-tiles-in-electron) solutions but nothing helped

Comment: What exactly from the links above have you tried? Have you called `invalidateSize()` on your map after the data has been added?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **Jan Wendland**

I used this solution [Leafletjs map - map.invalidateSize is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642925/leafletjs-map-map-invalidatesize-is-not-working) after your comment

```
setTimeout(function(){ map.invalidateSize()}, 400);
```